# Converting Public Key to uint[2] array to call Solidity contract function

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm trying to call the following Solidity contract: https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x8025532f39e089d8bb3ed783ccdd974ee8c3948f

The input parameters require the X and Y coordinates of the public key (uint[2]), but I have no idea how to get these values from an arbitrary public key (e.g. in hex or base64 format.

Answer (score 0):

The public key for Bitcoin/Ethereum elliptic curve comes in two possible formats:

- uncompressed: both coordinates X and Y are present (64 bytes)
- compressed: only Y is present plus a parity bit (you can solve for X using the equation) (32+1 bytes)